# Is it legal to give, or attempt to give, material, financial, etc. support to an insurrection, rebellion, etc. occurring in another country?

Tags: united-states

Suppose I've just learned that citizens of Hong Kong have decided to rebel against the Chinese government and are soliciting monetary donations from persons living in the United States. If I were to donate to the rebellion, would I be in violation of US law?

Comment: If you love a cause, **buy their merch**.  By that measure, the vast majority of us are supporting *the other side* in that conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not at present. Under [18 USC 2339B](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2339B), it is a crime to provide material support to a [foreign terrorist organization](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182#a_3), a designation made according to under section 219 of the Immigration and Nationality Act. The whole section containing that determination is [8 USC 1182](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182), then go to [(vi)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182#a_3_B_vi) (not VI) (vi) *“Terrorist organization” defined*. Because clause III says that an organization is a terrorist organization if it engages in acts defined as terrorism (the preceding clauses either refers you to a [different section](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1189) of title 8, or a published designation by the Sec'y of State), you cannot be certain by looking it up whether a given organization is a terrorist organization. [This](https://www.state.gov/foreign-terrorist-organizations/) is the current list, and there isn't anything obviously Hong Kong related.